# Links working locally but not online, ids not names and it still does not work

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I am trying to link one page to another using

```
<a href="about.html#1">about 1</a>
<a href="about.html#2">about 1</a>
<a href="about.html#3">about 1</a>
```

on index.html (in the menu)

on about.html I have

```
<div id="1"><h2>About 1</h2></div>
  <p>text text text</p>
<div id="2"><h2>About 2</h2></div>
  <p>text text text</p>
<div id="3"><h2>About 3</h2></div>
  <p>text text text</p>
```

when I click on the link in the menu on the index page it goes to the correct id when on my local machine, having uploaded the files to the server the link takes me to the top of the page only.

I tried linking the full url, tried applying the id to the h2 tags instead, everything works locally but not on the server, any ideas, it's driving me bonkers?

**The main thing is that this works locally but not when uploaded to the server....**

In context

```
<nav>
 <div class="menu">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="about.html#about">About1</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html#secondplace">About1</a></li>
       <li><a href="about.html#thirdplace">How3</a></li>
       </ul></li>
   <li><a href="ther.html">Ther</a>
      <ul>
    <li><a href="ther.html#ther1">S</a></li>
    <li><a href="ther.html#ther2">A</a></li>
    <li><a href="ther.html#ther3">A</a></li>
      </ul></li>
   <li><a href="testamonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
   <li><a href="services.html">Services</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="services.html#prices">Price list</a></li>
       <li><a href="services.html#desc">Descriptions</a></li>
       </ul></li>
       <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
     </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


<div id="about"><h2>About 1</h2></div>
      <p>text text text</p>
    <div id="secondplace"><h2>About 2</h2></div>
      <p>text text text</p>
    <div id="thirdplace"><h2>About 3</h2></div>
      <p>text text text</p>
```

Comment: Try adding quotation marks around the `href` attributes. Also `id` attributes should not begin with a numeric character (in HTML4).

Comment: @user3014529 does <div id="1"> and so on never exist on index.html? can we use javascript or jquery?

Comment: that was a typo! the id's nave names not numbers too

Comment: could you share the link to the page where this is not working

Comment: Have you specified a [doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration)... ***i.e.*** add the html5 `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your document.

Comment: <!doctype html> as it is html5, cant share a link as it is for a client

Comment: I have used submenus before and linked to ids and it works in the browser locally AND when i put it up online

Comment: If there's enough vertical space to scroll there's [no reason why this shouldn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/nzhU3/) - if you can't share a link then you'll have to replicate the problem in a demo for us.

Comment: Cheers, I think I will do just that, I can put it up, thanks for the help....